# Dummy variables based on values from different columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I currently have a data frame that looks as such:

```
dat2<-data.frame(
ID=c(100,101,102,103),
DEGREE_1=c("BA","BA","BA","BA"),
DEGREE_2=c(NA,"BA",NA,NA),
DEGREE_3=c(NA,"MS",NA,NA),
YEAR_DEGREE_1=c(1980,1990,2000,2004),
YEAR_DEGREE_2=c(NA,1992,NA,NA),
YEAR_DEGREE_3=c(NA,1996,NA,NA)
)

  ID DEGREE_1 DEGREE_2 DEGREE_3 YEAR_DEGREE_1 YEAR_DEGREE_2 YEAR_DEGREE_3
  100   BA      <NA>     <NA>       1980            NA            NA
  101   BA       BA       MS        1990          1992          1996
  102   BA      <NA>     <NA>       2000            NA            NA
  103   BA      <NA>     <NA>       2004            NA            NA
```

I would like to create dummy variables coded 0/1 based on what kind of degree was earned, using the completion of one BA degree as the base.

The completed data frame would have a second BA degree dummy, an MS degree dummy, and so on. For example, for ID 101, both dummies would have a value of 1. The completion of two MS degrees would not require a dummy, i.e. if someone completed two MS degrees, then the MS degree dummy would be 1 and there would be no dummy to signify completing two MS degrees.

[Like such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAaTM.png)

This is a simple snapshot of a much bigger data frame that has many different degrees types besides BA and MS, so it isn't ideal for me to create if/else statements for every single degree type.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using dummy_cols from the fastDummies package to first create dummy variables for each type of first degree earned. I then created ifelse statements to create additional dummy variables for the subsequent (2nd, 3rd, so on) degrees earned, conditional on whether those subsequent degrees had already been earned. However, since I have many different types of degrees, this is not ideal

Comment: Welcome welcome. This *is* a conditional statement question. Do you always have actually "empty values" or NAs when you do not have a degree? You could simply use if_else statements on the *presence of a value*, then the character string would not matter. As a side comment - depending on the further analysis you might want to consider restructuring your data into a long format...

Comment: @Tjebo In my larger data frame I have NAs when a subsequent degree was not earned. Could you please clarify what you mean by the if_else statement on the presence of a value? I do understand what you are getting at but cannot figure out how to apply it in my specific case. Apologies for my lack of experience in R.

I do agree with your point about having it in a long format, but I am required to reshape it so that each ID number has one row.

Comment: ideally, in this case then put `NA` instead of `""` into your sample dataframe

Comment: `require(dplyr)`  `dat2 %>% mutate(BA2nd = !is.na(DEGREE_2))`  should bring you on a track. One of multiple ways

Answer (score 1):

You could also include new columns and assign the value based on the DEGREE columns.

Including new columns, with all values equal 0:

```
dat2 <- cbind(dat2, BA_2nd = 0)
dat2 <- cbind(dat2, MS = 0)
```

Changing the value to 1, based on your conditions:

```
dat2[!is.na(dat2$DEGREE_2), 8] <- 1
dat2[!is.na(dat2$DEGREE_3) & dat2$DEGREE_3 == "MS", 9] <- 1
dat2
```

You can adapt it to all the conditions you have. This code generates only the output table that you included.

Comment: this is a bit convoluted. You may directly assign a new column with a simple one-liner `dat2$BA_2nd <- as.integer(!is.na(dat2$DEGREE_2))`...  Also I would recommend to select your columns by name and not by position because the position can very often change and this can seriously mess up your scripts.